# Pass html5 form custom attributes to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, form-data

This is the HTML that i created for the registration page

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" id="register_form">
        <input type="text" id="facebook-autocomplete" name="facebook" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete GJ-search">
        <input type="text" id="beatport-autocomplete" name="beatport" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete GJ-search" required>
        <input type="email" id="inputValidationEmail" name="email" class="form-control" >
        <input type="password" id="inputValidationPass" name="password" class="form-control" >
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="termsAndConditions" id="termsAndConditions" >
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="gdprAccept" id="gdpr" >
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block my-4 waves-effect z-depth-0" value="Submit" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript that extracts the form to JSON and console logging it and it works.

```
//stringify form to JSON string
const serialize_form = form => JSON.stringify(
    Array.from(new FormData(form).entries())
         .reduce((m, [ key, value ]) => Object.assign(m, { [key]: value }), {})
    );

$('#register_form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const json = serialize_form(this);
    console.log(json);
});
```

I add two new attributes to the beatport input by adding this jquery

```
$('.beatport #beatport-autocomplete').attr('data-beatport-id', "id pulled from api");
$('.beatport #beatport-autocomplete').attr('data-beatport-name', "name pulled from api");
```

The Json Result is after adding two new attributes is:

```
{"facebook":"big show","email":"dfghdfsghg@gmail.com","password":"fsdghfjgh","termsAndConditions":"on","gdprAccept":"on"}
```

You see that the two new attr are missing and when I add them the input looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="beatport-autocomplete" name="beatport" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete GJ-search" required data-beatport-id="12345" data-beatport-name="artist name">
```

and the JSON result should be like this:

```
{"facebook":"big show","beatportId":"12345","beatportName":"artist name","email":"dfghdfsghg@gmail.com","password":"fsdghfjgh","termsAndConditions":"on","gdprAccept":"on"}
```

Comment: Please, can you post in your question the result of the `console.log(json)`? Also, what exactly is the problem your are facing?

Comment: Insert what you asked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add data to your form you can use hidden input and set the value via js

HTML
`<input type="hidden" name="beatportID">`

JS
`$('[name="beatportID"]').attr('value', 'my data');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to extract data attributes from a html element and you are using jQuery already to set them i think the following might be what you are looking for. (Not exactly sure from your question what your desired result is) if possible perhaps you could explain a little further?

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Please check below for an example of that i mean.

Firstly lets say the following is your registration form.

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="phone" />
<input type="text" id="age" />
```

You would then add your two data attributes to let say the name input.

```
$('#name').attr('data-beatport-id', "id pulled from api");
$('#name').attr('data-beatport-name', "name pulled from api");
```

You can then serialize_form and add it to json variable.

```
let json = serialize_form(this);
```

And then use the following to get data attributes from the '#name' input.

```
json.beatport-name = $('#name').data("beatport-name")
json.beatport-id = $('#name').data("beatport-id")
```

You can then console log this json object.

`console.log(json)`

Comment: As you see I create two new attributes called data-beatport-id and data-beatport-name.  I want those two attributes to convert to JSON as well as the console.log result I posted. The bottom result is only what I want it to look like and its not shown in the console result

Comment: So if you create 2 new attributes that you then want to access and place inside the JSON array generated from the form. Why not generate the JSON from the form like you currently are and then separately grab the 2 data attributes $(this).data("beatport-id") & $(this).data("beatport-name") and just assign these to your json object? Please let me know if i am missing the point of your question here?

```let json = serialize_form(this);
json.beatport-id = $('#target').data("beatport-id")
json.beatport-name = $('#target').data("beatport-name")```

Comment: Its not working and not displaying in the console log.

Comment: It's supposed to display it like this after the user fill the form and serialize to JSON
        {"facebook":"big show","beatport-id":"146219","beatport-name":"Big Show","email":"dfghdfsghg@gmail.com","password":"fsdghfjgh","termsAndConditions":"on","gdprAccept":"on"}

Comment: I have modified my original answer to try and add a more in depth explanation of what i meant. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me rewrite the question like your answer.

Comment: After adding your code it is still consoles the same without the new attr

    `let json = serialize_form(this);
    json.beatport_id = serialize_form($("#beatport-autocomplete").data("beatport-id"));
    json.beatport_name = serialize_form($("#beatport-autocomplete").data("beatport-name"));
    console.log(json);`
That what consoles back

   `{"facebook":"big show","email":"igor@bigshow-music.com","password":"qwerty","termsAndConditions":"on","gdprAccept":"on"}`

Comment: `json.beatport_id = serialize_form($("#beatport-autocomplete").data("beatport-id"));`

This is incorrect it should just be 

json.beatport_id = $("#beatport-autocomplete").data("beatport-id");
And the same for name.

Also this seems like a very indirect solution to this problem.Would it be easier to add the value directly to the json object instead of adding it to the `<input>` to then pull it off. You could save the response from your API and then just do `json.beatport-name = api.beatport-name`

Comment: That's the result
`{"facebook":"big show","beatport":"Big Show","email":"info@novelgroup.info","password":"sdf","termsAndConditions":"on","gdprAccept":"on"}` of `let json = serialize_form(this);
        json.beatport_id = $("#beatport-autocomplete").data("beatport-id");
        json.beatport_name = $("#beatport-autocomplete").data("beatport-name");
        console.log(json);` so it's not there